# How to fix SIGABRT error? Transferring data between controller views?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to get the information in the text fields in one view controller and then put that information into the text view of another view controller. When I compile I get no error but when I run the program and click the find path button the program crash and gives me a sigabrt error.

Note: I didn't add any code to the viewcontroller(1st screen), therefore I didn't add a picture of it. And this is in Swift 4, Xcode 9

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could give us something better than screenshots? Maybe code snippets that can help us reproduce the issue? From what I can see - sorry, those screenshots on a 13 inch screen are horribly small - you are using a segue between these VCs you are trying to transfer "data" between. Maybe if you include *just* that - the prepare/perform code - we could help you with your problem. Please note - this request would help others with your issue too. Screenshots really don't work with search engines.

Comment: how would I just link the swift file?

Comment: @dfd I did add the prepare code in the bottom picture. And to create the segue I control clicked and dragged the find path button onto the screen I wanted it to segue to.

Comment: Please show your code as text, not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem I looked at the connection of each of my view controllers. Than I deleted the ones with an "!" next to the connection by clicking the "x" button on the connection.

this solved the problem